# Video array unable to get when last video plays the next button to play again starting at first video in array

Tags: javascript, button, video, arraylist

The videos all play when called. In search, addEventListener was suggested. Alas, no help. Perhaps I'm wording it wrong, but how to get the next button to go back to the first video in the array after the last video has played. JavaScript I am still learning to figure out its logic, and it is not a clean beast. Messy life is my outlook with JS. I have removed the videos as they are adult in nature (18+++), and do not want to offend anyone. The noted out  are what I have tried that have no impact or negative impact on how the current setup functions.

```js
let vids = [".mp4", ".mp4", ".mp4"]

// videoCount = vids.length;does nothing




  // const found = vids.find(element => element < 3); does nothing
  
//Adultvideo.addEventListener('ended', next, false); does nothing

 let i = 0;
 let src=vids[i];
function next(e)  {
  i++;
   
        if (i > 3){ 
        
       // return src; does nothing
    //return i; //does nothing

//const found = vids.find(element => element === 0); does nothing
     
     // Adultvideo.load(); does nothing
        
          //Adultvideo.play(vids[i]); does nothing

// return AdultVideo.trigger('loadstart');
       
       } 
        
        
      document.getElementById("Adultvideo").src=vids[i];
       
      
     } 
      // document.getElementById('Adultvideo').reset(src); does nothing
      //src.Adultvideo.play(i);does nothing
       
  //playVideo(i);
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Adult Male Video 18 Plus !</h1></header>
  <main>
  <section class="vidcontainer">
    
    <!-- Don't put control into element unless you are an adult 18+ for the vid could offend and disturb you. Likewise, do not push play either as the video could offend and disturb you -->  
    <!-- had to add height to control poster --> 
   <video id="Adultvideo" muted width="500" height="340"  poster="">
  
  <source id="Adultvideo"  muted src="" type="video/mp4">
   
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
    

<div class="Vcontrol"> 
  <div class="Vpanel">Control Panel</div>
  <button onclick="playVideo();">&#9655;</button>

<button onclick="pauseVideo();">&#8214;</button>
<button onclick="stopVideo();">⬜</button>
<button onclick="rewindVideo();">
  &#10226;</button>
  <button onclick="next();"><span class="reduce">&#x25b7;&#x25B7;</span>    &#x1D100;</button>
 
    </div>
     </section></main>
  
  <!-- I wish there was better instruction on this script here as copy and paste is not very good instruction -->


  <script>
  
   const Adultvideo=document.querySelector("#Adultvideo");
   
  
   
   
function playVideo() {
  Adultvideo.play();
}
function pauseVideo() {
  Adultvideo.pause();
}
function stopVideo() {
  Adultvideo.load();
}  
function rewindVideo() {
  Adultvideo.currentTime= 0;
  
  <!-- this function does not work, and unable to locate how to correct. All the extra JS does not help. The teaching sucks for this course. It does work, but still not perfect -->
  function next() {
    Adultvideo.next();
    
  }
// Adultvideo.addEventListener('ended', next, false); affects nothing
}
 // Adultvideo.addEventListener('ended', next, false); //affects nothing
   
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"How to get the next button to go back to the first video in the array after the last video..."*

Positions in Array start from zero as first item, so an array with 3 items has positions (index) of:

```
array[0], array[1], array[2]
```

As you can see the last item's index is 2, which is just `minus 1` from a total array length of 3 items. In other words, last item pos can be calculated from `array.length - 1` (*eg:* `3 - 1` = 2).

Try something like this:

```
<script>

var i = 0;
var vids = ["first.mp4", "second.mp4", "third.mp4"]; //has positions [0, 1, 2] 
var videoCount = vids.length; //is 3

var myPlayer = document.getElementById("Adultvideo");

function playVideo() { myPlayer.play(); }
function pauseVideo() { myPlayer.pause(); }
function stopVideo() { myPlayer.currentTime = 0; myPlayer.pause();  }  
function rewindVideo() { myPlayer.currentTime = 0; }

function next()
{
    i++; //# count range is from 0 up to 2 (since total is 3 items)

    if (i == 2) { i = 0; } //reset after third count
    //if (i == (vids.length - 1) ) { i = 0; } //or auto-detect total items then reset 

    myPlayer.src = vids[i];
    myPlayer.play();
} 
     
</script>
```

Comment: The changing of the existing if argument to i == 3 and adding { i = 0 ; }  with the myPlayer.play was the solution. Thank you VC.  I can read the code and have the light go on. Learning JS is not how I think to approach a solution, so I do appreciate simplicity over complex for no reason. Thank you again very much!

Answer (score 1):

The main question you asked is **"how [do I] get the next button to go back to the first video"**...

To answer that, the answer is fairly straightforward: Use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder). This is a common programming practice for wrapping a value.

For example:

```js
// Go to the next video (and wrap)
i = (i + 1) % vids.length;

// Load the new video selection
videoSrcEl.src = vids[i];
videoEl.load();
```

**EDIT**:

The reason this works is because `i++` is equivalent to `i = i + 1` and the remainder after division will always be between 0 and n - 1. That second part sounds more complicated than it is, so let's just look at `i % 3` as `i` changes (for `n = 3`):

- If i = 0, then `i % 3` = 0
- If i = 1, then `i % 3` = 1
- If i = 2, then `i % 3` = 2
- If i = 3, then `i % 3` = 0
- If i = 4, then `i % 3` = 1
- If i = 5, then `i % 3` = 2
- If i = 6, then `i % 3` = 0

...notice the pattern?

An alternative would be to use an `if` statement:

```js
// Go to the next video (and wrap)
i++;
if (i > vids.length - 1) {
  i = 0;
}

// Load the new video selection
videoSrcEl.src = vids[i];
videoEl.load();
```

---

Beyond that question, though, I'd like to propose a few changes to the rest of your code:

- Don't use `id="Adultvideo"` on both the `<video>` and the nested `<source>`. IDs are expected to be unique.
- Don't use inline JS like `onclick="playVideo();"`. This requires a global function, which is rarely what you really want. The better way is to use `playButton.addEventListener('click', playVideo)` in the JS somewhere (and I add an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to make sure nothing is global by accident)

I made a working example below, which uses a lot of newer JS syntax, but I hope you can make sense of it. These may be just my preference but note that:

- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do have some differences from regular functions but they're mostly equivalent. I use them because they're shorter
- I find it easier to just use classes and avoid IDs in almost all cases. I do separate CSS classes from JS classes, though
- `const` prevents certain changes (re-assignment), but otherwise works like `let`

```js
// IIFE
;(() => {
  // Create a couple reusable functions (DRY up the code below)
  const el = s => document.querySelector(`.js-${s}`)
  const click = (s, fn) => el(s).addEventListener('click', fn)

  // Get references to DOM elements (see HTML)
  const videoEl = el('video')
  const videoSrcEl = el('video-src')

  // List of videos (I found a few random ones from across the web)
  const vids = [
    'https://i.imgur.com/tTaZyQC.mp4',
    'https://i.imgur.com/WHifiaH.mp4',
    'http://giant.gfycat.com/FineDangerousFruitbat.mp4'
  ]

  let i = 0 // <-- which video is currently selected

  // Handle clicks
  click('play', () => { videoEl.play() })
  click('pause', () => { videoEl.pause() })
  click('stop', () => { videoEl.load() })
  click('rewind', () => { videoEl.currentTime = 0 })
  click('next', () => {
    // Go to the next video (and wrap)
    i = (i + 1) % vids.length

    // Load the new video selection
    videoSrcEl.src = vids[i]
    videoEl.load()
  })

  // Load the first video
  videoSrcEl.src = vids[i]
})()
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title Here</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <section class="video">
    <video class="js-video" muted width="500" height="340" poster="">
      <source class="js-video-src" muted src="" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <div class="video-control">
      <div class="video-panel">Control Panel</div>
      <button class="js-play">&#9655;</button>
      <button class="js-pause">&#8214;</button>
      <button class="js-stop">⬜</button>
      <button class="js-rewind">&#10226;</button>
      <button class="js-next">
        <span class="reduce">&#x25b7;&#x25B7;</span>&#x1D100;
      </button>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am really still at the beginnings of JS. I was looking for a solution to what I have that works through the videos. I can make only 40% out of your code. I'm not going to get stressed out of things that should be clear not confusing. No programming is worth getting tension headaches over.  Thank you again.

Comment: Did the first part answer your main question?

Comment: No. Your code writing is advanced. I'm like JS 100 minus 90.  I'm not into copy and paste as one learns nothings. I'm sure you'd agree. That has been my complaint about JS all along. Nothing in life should provide headaches of frustration. Sorry, but not. No insult to you. A simple if else should be able to solve, but not with JavaScript. Logically, it should be if i++ ends stop else repeat i. Seriously, I'm sure you can see the logic in that. I mean function next () plays through the vids. Correct? An if else, or if then statement with a return seems more logical than copy and pasting.

Comment: I can understand the feelings of frustration. Learning a new language is certainly never easy. If I understand correctly, though, your requirement is that the answer must be an `if` statement? I can also provide one of those in an edit to my answer.

Comment: @darryl Edit made. Hope that helps!

Comment: I appreciate your help, but VC below brought forward a clean simple non-complex recommendation that well,,, solved using an if . it's nothing more than an array of porn vids. An if should be sufficient to solve. The code I provided passed checker sources I was provided by edx. I get the => for function as I'm trying to learn JS with codeacademy as well, but parts of its lessons are written in jibber word arrangement as edx. Nothing in life is worth getting frustrated over to the point of cursing, which JS brings forward. If you have a good JS learning course lead, I'm all ears. Thank you.